# MySQL UPDATE with needed subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

For school I've got the following assignment to UPDATE data into a database:

> Give all the employees (located into the *employee* table)
>   who work on a project where the employee "*50*" (employee code) works on as well a salary raise of 250 euro

I know I had to get the `SAL` column in the *employee* and then raise it by 250 euro. I currently did this by the following query.

```
UPDATE `work` AS work
INNER JOIN `employee` AS employee ON employee.`CODE` = work.`W_CODE`
SET employee.`SAL` = (employee.`SAL` + 250)
WHERE work.`P_CODE` IN  ( # .... );
```

The `P_CODE` column stands for the project identifier. In the `work` table, all *employee*'s with the current project they are working on are listed.

For getting the projects where the *employee* with the code *50* worked on, I made the following subquery:

```
UPDATE `work` AS work
INNER JOIN `employee` AS employee ON employee.`CODE` = work.`W_CODE`
SET employee.`SAL` = (employee.`SAL` + 250)
WHERE work.`P_CODE` IN (SELECT work.`P_CODE` 
                        FROM `work` AS work
                        INNER JOIN `employee` AS employee ON `employee`.`CODE` = work.`W_CODE`
                        WHERE employee.`CODE` = "50");
```

When running this query, I get this error:

> Error Code: 1093. Table 'work' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

For my own try,  I did some research and found I can't use the same table twice for this.

**Questions**

How can I fix this query where the sub-query will work? Can it be combined in my first join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using different  alias eg: w1 and w2 for work

```
UPDATE `work` 
    AS w1

    INNER JOIN `employee` AS employee
        on employee.`CODE` = w1.`W_CODE`

    SET employee.`SAL` = (employee.`SAL` + 250)

    WHERE w1.`P_CODE` IN  ( select t.my_code from (
    SELECT w2.`P_CODE` as my_code 
        FROM `work` AS w2
        INNER JOIN `employee` AS employee
            ON `employee`.`CODE` = w2.`W_CODE`
        WHERE employee.`CODE` = "50"
    )  t ) ;
```

Comment: It gives `Error Code: 1093. Table 'w1' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data` back.. I don't even understand what's going on.

Comment: i have update the answer forcing  a dinamic temp table

Comment: Why is the `t` there at the end?

Comment: @bas   t  is a  dinamic temp table name .  when you create a table this way  you must assign a name  .. for eventually refer to the table column .. in you case you don't need to refer to this table column but in some case you need  eg: work.p_code = t.my_code ..

Comment: But aren't you doing that with the `my_code` alias?

Comment: @Bas   my_code is the alias of a column .. t is the name of the table.  i have update the answer adding the table name at the column alias .. t.my_code .. .. . i hope this is clear and mostly  that the query work right

Comment: That explains it! Why did a subquery in a subquery work now though?

Comment: @Bas  . the subquery  work in this way becase the rdbms engine if forced to create a temporary table in this way  don't update the same table that is select  .. but preserve the needed  data in the forced  temp table .. hope this is clear .. and if my answer is right please mark it as accepted .

Answer (score 0):

update employee as  e1 set e1.Salary=(e1.Salary+20)
  where e1.workId IN 
  (
  select workId from (
        select e2.workId  from employee as  e2 inner join works  as w2 on e2.workId=w2.id 
           where e2.workId=50
      ) as x)

Refer link for detail explanation:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

@Bas in above query i have considered employee table to be updated so u can make changes accordingly.

this query works fine if structure is like this:

1)Employee table
..............
empid(P key)   |  workId(F key) | Name  |salary

2)Work table
id (P key) | workcode